# Searching a row in a file java spring batch

Tags: java, spring, performance, file, spring-batch

I have 2 files File A and History file. I have to iterate over each row in file A and look up for its entry in History file, if that entry is found i need to write this in a new file A_History. How can i achieve this in java.

Time and performance are critical factors. I would like to achieve this without bumping memory. 
I searched for spring batch but nothing seems to be available there. Any ideas ?

Comment: Check out Apache Lucene.

Comment: I tried apache lucene and for each line in file i created a document and added to the index dir,  but for a 2.5GB file it is creating index dir of almost 8GB and it took it almost 30-45 mins to create the index, we cant have this much delay, and the file wil keep on changing daily so everyday i have to do this activity of creating index, doesnt fit for our needs :(

Comment: That's a lot of indexes. You should try to minimize index creation, or else you will spend more time in indexing rather than searching.

Comment: When you say minimize index creation, do you mean that i should club together some rows and then created document of clubbed rows ?  If i do so then on search it will give me a set of rows i will again have to iterate on the rows and find the data. Or any other approach ?

I am thinking that i will parse the file 1time and using randomaccessreader i will maintain the hashcode and positionbyteoffset of each line in a map, so when i have to search i lookup the map to get byteoffset and then using randomaccessreader i can just seek to the location and get that line ?

Comment: Yes, Ofcourse that's the point. Index should only help you narrow down, not do the entire search. The way you are doing is you are adding indexes for every paragraph instead of every chapter in a book. That's bound to create problems.

Comment: @WeareBorg, Please see the updated commment.

Comment: That sounds good, but unfortunately I am not that much of an expert in Luecene, I think you should wait for someone else, or better yet, as you have now decided your strategy, you might want to try it, and post a new question asking for users if this is the optimum way.